# Is there an accumarray() that takes matrix as `val`?

Tags: matlab, matrix, grouping, accumarray

[accumarray()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html)'s  `val` argument must be a vector. In my case I need columns of a matrix to be summed (or averaged). Is there a function or a method to achieve this?

What I am doing now is in a for loop I am summing column values separately:

```
for iCol = 1:nCols
    means(:,iCol) = accumarray(labels', X(:,iCol));
end
```

Comment: Since R2015b there is: [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution is to replicate the row indices in `labels` and add another column of column indices. Then you can reshape `X` into a column vector and apply [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) once:

```
labels = [repmat(labels(:),nCols,1) ...            % Replicate the row indices
          kron(1:nCols,ones(1,numel(labels))).'];  % Create column indices
totals = accumarray(labels,X(:));  % I used "totals" instead of "means"
```

### How it works...

`A = accumarray(subs,val)` for a column vector `subs` and vector `val` works by adding the number in `val(i)` to the total in row `subs(i)` in the output column vector `A`. However, `subs` can contain more than just row indices. It can contain subscript indices for multiple dimensions to assign values to in the output. This feature is what allows you to handle an input `val` that is a matrix instead of a vector.

First, the input for `val` can be reshaped into a column vector using the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) `X(:)`. Next, in order to keep track of which column in the output the values in `X(:)` should be placed, we can modify the input `subs` to include an additional column index. To illustrate how this works, I'll use these sample inputs:

```
labels = [3; 1; 1];
X = [1 2 3; ...
     4 5 6; ...
     7 8 9];
nCols = 3
```

And here are what the variables in the above code end up looking like:

```
labels = 3 1    X(:) = 1    totals = 11 13 15
         1 1           4              0  0  0
         1 1           7              1  2  3
         3 2           2
         1 2           5
         1 2           8
         3 3           3
         1 3           6
         1 3           9
```

Notice, for example, that the values `1 4 7` that were originally in the first column of `X` will only be accumulated in the first column of the output, as denoted by the ones in the first three rows of the second column of `labels`. The resulting output should be the same as what you would have gotten by using the code in the question where you loop over each column to perform the accumulation.

Comment: @gnovice: In this case, the result would be a maxLabels-by-1 array, correct?

Comment: @Jonas: Actually, the result should be a max(labels)-by-nCols matrix, although I'm not anywhere that I can double-check the code right now.

Comment: @gnovice: Oh, now I understand. Beautiful!

Comment: @gnovice: I am afraid, I did not quite get what it does. I am kind of new to MATLAB. Can you explain further or should I fiddle with it more to understand? I am not sure which one will help most :)

Comment: @nimcap: I added an explanation to my answer to help make it more clear how the code works.

Comment: @gnovice I was really surprised to see that both this and @yibo-yang's solution perform significantly slower than the for loop version. I have shared all 3 implementations here: https://octave-online.net/bucket~LpVkvo6tB356yn1e6CodDS . Run it by calling `benchmarkComputeCentroids(100,100,10,1);` .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more intuitive (maybe more efficient) way borrowed from [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63214-how-to-use-accumarray-over-a-matrix-avoiding-a-loop#answer_74813) (the original answer assumes column-major inputs so I transposed them):

```
[xx, yy] = ndgrid(labels,1:size(X, 1));
totals = accumarray([yy(:) xx(:) ], reshape(X.', 1, []));
```

Example:

```
X = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
labels = [2; 1; 3; 1];
```

gives 
`totals = [6 1 3; 14 5 7]`.

If you want to do this row-wise then there's no need to transpose, just:

```
[xx, yy] = ndgrid(labels,1:size(X, 2));
totals = accumarray([xx(:) yy(:)], X(:));
```