# sum over indexes

Tags: matlab, octave

Suppose I have

```
A = [10 20 30 40];
idx = [1 1 1 2];
result = [0 0];
```

I need to sum A over indexes in idx so that

```
result(1) = A(1) + A(2) + A(3);
result(2) = A(4);
```

I implemented the code

```
for i=1:length(idx)
  result(idx(i)) += A(i);
end
```

How can I transform it to more octave-standard code, if possible one-liner?

Comment: Also see a more general question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350735/is-there-an-accumarray-that-takes-matrix-as-val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), it does exactly what you are asking for, it only needs its first input as a column:

```
A = [10 20 30 40];
idx = [1 1 1 2];
result = accumarray(idx',A)

  result =

      60
      40
```

and yes, this also works in octave ;) ([link](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Accumulation.html))