# MATLAB find mean of column in matrix using two different indices

Tags: matlab, loops, mean

I have a `22007x3` matrix with data in column 3 and two separate indices in columns 1 and 2.

eg.

```
x = 

    1   3   4
    1   3   5
    1   3   5
    1   16  4
    1   16  3
    1   16  4
    2   4   1
    2   4   3
    2   11  2
    2   11  3
    2   11  2
```

I need to find the mean of the values in column 3 when the values in column 1 are the same AND the values in column 2 are the same, to end up with something like:

```
ans = 

    1   3   4.6667
    1   16  3.6667
    2   4   2
    2   11  2.3333
```

Please bear in mind that in my data, the number of times the values in column 1 and 2 occur can be different.

Two options I've tried already are the `meshgrid`/`accumarray` option, using two distinct `unique` functions and a 3D array:

```
[U, ix, iu] = unique(x(:, 1));
[U2,ix2,iu2] = unique(x(:,2));
[c, r, j] = meshgrid((1:size(x(:, 1), 2)), iu, iu2);
totals = accumarray([r(:), c(:), j(:)], x(:), [], @nanmean);
```

which gives me this:

```
??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Error in ==> meshgrid at 60
    xx = xx(ones(ny,1),:,ones(nz,1));
```

and the loop option,

```
for i=1:size(x,1)
    if x(i,2)== x(i+1,2);
        totals(i,:)=accumarray(x(:,1),x(:,3),[],@nanmean);
    end
end
```

which is obviously so very, very wrong, not least because of the `x(i+1,2)` bit.

I'm also considering creating separate matrices depending on how many times a value in column 1 occurs, but that would be long and inefficient, so I'm loathe to go down that road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group on the first two columns with a `unique(...,'rows')`, then **accumulate only the third column** (always the best approach to accumulate only where accumulation really happens, thus avoiding indices, i.e. the first two columns, which you can reattach with `unX`):

```
[unX,~,subs] = unique(x(:,1:2),'rows');
out          = [unX accumarray(subs,x(:,3),[],@nanmean)];

out =
            1            3       4.6667
            1           16       3.6667
            2            4            2
            2           11       2.33
```

Comment: This should be compatible with Eitan's manswer to your previous question as well (i.e. when you want to mix the two): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086874/matlab-find-and-apply-function-to-values-of-repeated-indices/16087295#16087295

Comment: That's the one! Thanks Oleg!

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal opportunity to use sparse matrix math.

```
x = [ 1 2 5;
      1 2 7;
      2 4 6;
      3 4 6;
      1 4 8;
      2 4 8;
      1 1 10]; % for example

SM = sparse(x(:,1),x(:,2), x(:,3); 
disp(SM)
```

Result:

```
(1,1)   10
(1,2)   12
(1,4)    8
(2,4)   14
(3,6)    7
```

As you can see, we did the "accumulate same indices into same container" in one fell swoop.  Now you need to know how many elements you have:

```
NE = sparse(x(:,1), x(:,2), ones(size(x(:,1))));
disp(NE);
```

Result:

```
(1,1)   1
(1,2)   2
(1,4)   1
(2,4)   2
(3,6)   1
```

Finally, you divide one by the other to get the mean (only use elements that have a value):

```
matrixMean = SM;
nz = find(NE>0);
matrixMean(nz) = SM(nz) ./ NE(nz);
```

If you then `disp(matrixMean)`, you get

```
(1,1)    10
(1,2)     6
(1,4)     8
(2,4)     7
(3,6)     7
```

If you want to access the individual elements differently, then after you have computed SM and NE you can do

```
[i j n] = find(NE);
matrixMean = SM(i,j)./NE(i,j);
disp([i(:) j(:) nonzeros(matrixMean)]);
```