# Calculate the mean of set of rows in a matrix

Tags: matlab

How can I calculate the mean of a group of rows and put the in a matrix such as:

```
1  4   5
1  34  4
1  65  0
1  5   3
2  3   44
2  52  4
2  5   6
3  9   2
3  9   1
3  9   9
```

So I can have a matrix as

```
1  27 4 
2  20 18
3  9  4
```

Thx

Comment: What defines a "group of rows"? Is it the value in the first column?

Comment: @Shai Oh, these guys are sitting in the same CS class, I see.

Comment: @H2CO3 and what a class it is...

Comment: Hello,
It is not a class. I have the power reading transferred from one station to another through transmission lines. The reading was taken every hour for the whole year. So I want to calculate the mean of power loss of every day.

Comment: @H2CO3 What class is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming original data is in matrix `A`:

```
indx=unique(A(:,1));
for ii=1:numel(indx)
  RowMean(ii,:)=mean(A(1,:)==indx(ii),:);
end
```

Comment: You can avoid the for loop by using the `accumarray` function, as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086874#16087358)...

Comment: @eitan you are right . This is "a" way, not the "best" way. Thanks for the link.