# Operation on a column with respect to other columns

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

Looking at following code:

```
x=[2,3;1,4;1,5;2,4;3,1;3,4];
u=unique(x(:,1));
for i=1:length(u)
    n(i,:)=mean(x(x(:,1)==u(i),:))
end
```

Is there anyway to avoid the `for` loop, and make the code simpler? Basically, what I want to do is to group the rows based on a the value of a column and apply an operation on the other values for a given "group".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB find and apply function to values of repeated indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086874/matlab-find-and-apply-function-to-values-of-repeated-indices)

Comment: the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16087141/1904719

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a job for the powerful [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with the `mean` function. Basically use values in the 1st column of `x` as subscripts and the values from the 2nd column as actual values on which you perform the desired calculation:

```
n2 = accumarray((x(:,1)),x(:,2),[],@mean)

out = [unique(x(:,1)) n2]

out =

    1.0000    4.5000
    2.0000    3.5000
    3.0000    2.5000
```

yay!

Comment: Instead of writing `@(x) mean(x)` as function, it recognises `@mean` by itself, it being a built-in. No need of anonymising it.

Comment: oh right I keep forgetting about that thanks @Adriaan