# Sum up every nth row in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing, vectorization

Is there any easy way to sum up every nth row in Matlab? 
Lets say I have:

```
A =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
13    14    15
16    17    18
```

I wish to add every 2 rows, like this: `row1+row3+row5`, and then `row2+row4+row6`, so my output is:

```
B =

21    24    27
30    33    36
```

I know that it is possible to do it by `sum(A(1:2:end,:))` but this is not helpful if you have large matrix and many nth rows, `for` loop is another option but I couldn't get it working so far. Do you have any suggestions/solutions how this could be solved with a `for` loop, or maybe there is a built-in function?

Comment: What's wrong with `sum(A(1:2:end,:)) for large matrices`?

Comment: from my example `sum(A(1:2:end,:)` gives me `21 24 27` whereas to get `30 33 36` i have to use `sum(A(2:2:end,:)` and if you have many of these nth rows then it becomes a bit tricky. Maybe I was unclear in my question about it.

Comment: Just curious, how big could be the number of rows and columns in `A`?

Comment: @vaitas Though the given solutions are fine, I have included one that is basically a generalization of what you already did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about that?

```
B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) sum(A(x:n:end,:)),1:n,'uni',0)')
```

I first thought about using `accumarray` but it requires a vector as input. It's still possible, if you follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4350735/2605073).

Another accumarray alternative:

```
[a,b] = size(A);
idx = bsxfun(@plus, 1:b,repmat([0:b:b*n-1]',a/n,1)) 
B = reshape(accumarray(idx(:),A(:)),b,[]).'
```

Comment: That `accumarray + bsxfun` looks fast! +1

Comment: It seems like this solution requires `M` to be an integer multiple of `n`. This need not be a problem, but should be kept in mind.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Yes that is true, the first solution should work though. But without this condition the whole summing up would make no sense to me, as there would be no comparability of the results for all groups.

Comment: @Divakar but it isn't! not at all ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk That's right, spoke too soon, but still good terse code :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid `arrayfun` for a general `n` case, you can use some reshaping methods. One such approach could be this -

```
[M,N] = size(A); %// Get the size of A for later usage
rowd = reshape(1:M,n,M/n)'; %// Get new row indices based on every nth selection
A1 = A(rowd(:),:); %// Reshaped A that has all the nth rows packed up consecutively for easing summing up
A2 = reshape(A1,M/n,[]); %// Reshape into a matrix with the number of rows equal to number of rows in each nth grouping
out = reshape(sum(A2),[],N); %// Get the final output by summing across columns and reshaping into the N-column format as with A
```

Comment: @vaitas Great!! Since you have large matrices, it would be interesting to see some benchmark results across the techniques mentioned here in the solutions!

Comment: @Divakar I let you do that task this time ... ;)

Comment: @Bentoy13! I just did few benchmarks with number of columns of `30` and mine looked faster :D Well about posting such benchmark results..not sure at this moment :)

Comment: @Divakar Ok, I want to play! :P Let's wait for more solutions.

Comment: It seems like this solution requires `M` to be an integer multiple of `n`. This need not be a problem, but should be kept in mind.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Agreed that's the assumption here.

Answer (score 4):

## Benchmark for all solutions

([Thanks to Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047303/2605073) for the Benchmark-code)

```
function [t,v] = nthSum()
    n = 3; 
    A = randi(100,10000*n,3);

    % functions to compare
    fcns = {
        @() sum1(A,n);
        @() sum2(A,n);
        @() sum3(A,n);
        @() sum4(A,n);
        @() sum5(A,n);
        @() sum6(A,n);
    };

    % timeit
    t = zeros(6,1);
    for ii = 1:100;
        t = t + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
    end

    % check results
    v = cellfun(@feval, fcns, 'UniformOutput',false);
    assert(isequal(v{:}));
end

function B = sum1(A,n)   %thewaywewalk#1
    [a,b] = size(A);
    idx = bsxfun(@plus, 1:b,repmat([0:b:b*n-1]',a/n,1)); 
    B = reshape(accumarray(idx(:),A(:)),b,[]).';
end

function B = sum2(A,n)  %thewaywewalk#2
    B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) sum(A(x:n:end,:)),1:n,'uni',0)');
end

function B = sum3(A,n) %Dennis Jaheruddin
    B=zeros(n,size(A,2));

    for k=1:n
        B(k,:)=sum(A(k:n:end,:),1);
    end
end

function B = sum4(A,n) %Luis Mendo
    B = squeeze(sum(reshape(permute(A, [1 3 2]), n,[] ,size(A,2)), 2));
end

function B = sum5(A,n) % Bentoy13
    [k,l] = size(A);
    B = sum(reshape([A',zeros(l,mod(-k,n))],l,n,ceil(k/n)),3)';
end

function B = sum6(A,n) % Divakar
    [M,N] = size(A); 
    rowd = reshape(1:M,n,M/n)'; 
    A1 = A(rowd(:),:);
    A2 = reshape(A1,M/n,[]); 
    B = reshape(sum(A2),[],N);
end
```

Results for 100 runs each and a `30000x3` Matrix `A`

```
0.1616s   %// thewaywewalk#1
0.0667s   %// thewaywewalk#2
0.0499s   %// Dennis Jaheruddin
0.0211s   %// Luis Mendo
0.0791s   %// Bentoy13
0.0784s   %// Divakar
```

Clear winner & loser, the rest is very close.
Especially the most simple solution (for loop) by Dennis is top notch ;)

**Interesting how everything changes for large row lengths**

Results for 100 runs each and a `3000x1000` Matrix `A`

```
6.5646s   %// thewaywewalk#1
2.6314s   %// thewaywewalk#2
2.5939s   %// Dennis Jaheruddin
0.6412s   %// Luis Mendo
4.1996s   %// Bentoy13
1.9975s   %// Divakar
```

**Performance along number of rows**

Results averaged on 1000 runs, for input matrix size from 10 * 25 to 1e6 * 25 elements.

[image]

Data:

```
N               10          20          50          100         200         500         1e+03       2e+03       5e+03       1e+04       2e+04       5e+04   1e+05   2e+05   5e+05   1e+06
thewaywewalk #1     0.000282    0.000401    0.000399    0.000341    0.000276    0.000306    0.000358    0.000538    0.00109     0.0015      0.00283     0.0111  0.021   0.0427  0.112   0.224
thewaywewalk #2     7.15e-05    0.000106    0.000129    0.000137    0.000149    0.000262    0.000433    0.000929    0.00313     0.00581     0.0122      0.0289  0.0567  0.121   0.327   0.635
Divakar             3.21e-05    4.36e-05    4.65e-05    4.63e-05    4.52e-05    6.86e-05    0.000116    0.00024     0.000668    0.00179     0.00378     0.00962 0.0193  0.0442  0.116   0.245
Bentoy13            4.58e-05    6.48e-05    7.43e-05    7.31e-05    7.16e-05    0.000103    0.000192    0.000387    0.00115     0.0028      0.00585     0.015   0.0303  0.0623  0.158   0.298
Dennis Jaheruddin   3.76e-05    5.54e-05    6.07e-05    6.25e-05    6.47e-05    0.000114    0.000183    0.000376    0.000999    0.00165     0.00345     0.0162  0.0318  0.0657  0.163   0.326
Luis Mendo          7.44e-05    0.000108    0.00011     9.45e-05    7.83e-05    8.56e-05    0.000102    0.000154    0.000323    0.000452    0.000892    0.00203 0.00374 0.00741 0.0186  0.0368
```

For small matrices (below 1000 rows), the solution from Divakar is the fastest; for large matrices, the solution from Luis Mendo is clearly the best one.

Comment: I think this answer would be owned by community wiki. Beside that point, great work; I run myself another benchmark in the same time, and the conclusions are a bit different, I will add info to the post if you allow me to do so.

Comment: @Bentoy13 go ahead ;)

Comment: Thank you. I need a little more time, I rerun my benchmark to add the timing of the solution from Luis Mendo.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thank you for the results!! I am also curious about if the number of columns are increased too, would it be possible? Or too much of work maybe with two variables? Nevertheless, great thanks! Oh you just did, Kool!

Comment: @Divakar have you seen the last edit, or do you mean something different?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yeah the last edit has the results that I was looking for, thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @Bentoy13! Your results makes sense I guess! its great and thanks for your efforts too! Guess OP can use a switch based on the datasize :)

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for the effort! Answers like this make SO great

Comment: you're welcome. Was basically copy&paste :p and the chart is by bentoy!

Answer (score 3):

Even if there is already an accepted answer, let's try to do this differently.

The idea here is to reshape the original matrix into a 3D array in order to sum up along one dimension. But we have to take care about the fact that the size of A may not be a multiple of n.

Let's begin with some notations:

```
[k,l] = size(A);
```

In order to reshape, we must have `k=n*x` (x integer). If it's not the case, we must pad A with rows of 0. If `k=n*x+y`, y being the reminder of the euclidian division of k by n, we have to concatenate n-y rows of 0 to A (or 0 is y==0). Using Matlab `mod` function, it translates to:

```
A1 = [A;zeros(mod(-k,n),l)];
```

Recall that `mod(-k,n)` is positive.

Now, you want to sum rows and not columns: we want to get a 3D array with rows kept intact, and columns distributed on rows. So I must transpose the array, and reshape it:

```
A2 = reshape(A1',l,n,ceil(k/n));
```

Your result is then simply the sum along the 3rd dimension, with transposing back:

```
B = sum(A2,3)';
```

As a conclusion, let's build a nearly one-liner (I left k and l apart, for clarity ... ok, for conciseness):

```
[k,l] = size(A);
B = sum(reshape([A',zeros(l,mod(-k,n))],l,n,ceil(k/n)),3)';
```

Answer (score 3):

Permuting dimensions and reshaping:

```
B = squeeze(sum(reshape(permute(A, [1 3 2]), n,[],size(A,2)), 2));
```

Comment: Nice but tough one, I've learned something with `permute` here.

Answer (score 1):

I still think a `for` loop would be simple here, and probably reasonably efficient if you have long matrices:

```
A = [ 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
13    14    15
16    17    18];

n=2;
result=zeros(n,size(A,2));

for k=1:n
   result(k,:)=sum(A(k:n:end,:),1);
end
```