# Average of subgroup of 2nd column, grouped by 1st column

Tags: matlab, data-manipulation

Suppose I have matrix A. 1st column is "group". Then I want to calculate the average of 2nd column for each group. So I want to create B.

```
A=
 1  2
 1  3
 2  4
 2  2

B=
 1  2.5
 2  3
```

The best thing I did until now is to construct a long for and if loop and use average function to get to B.

But I guess there will be more simple method. Is there?

Comment: [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

Comment: @Dan Lol, I never knew about accumarray. I basically wrote my own mex function for this case :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't used [`accumarray`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) before, so due to the comment by @Dan I decided to give it a try.

At first I tried a naive version and used `histc` to count occurrences to get the desired mean values... (Note that accumarray will sort the output the same order as `unique`, so mean will be calculated correctly)

```
%// Naive version
ua = unique(A(:,1)); %// use as histc bins (or sorted "group" values)
result = accumarray(A(:,1), A(:,2)) ./ histc(A(:,1), uA);
```

Here, `accumarray` operates by summing over all entries in `A(:,2)` corresponding to identical subscripts in `A(:,1)`.

But then I realised that by passing the optional `fun` argument to `accumarray` changing "summing" to "mean", you can do this as a one-liner:

```
%// one-liner
result = accumarray(A(:,1), A(:,2), [], @mean);
```

Comment: accumarray is the way to go if you just need to aggregate an array. If you need to aggregate up full rows of a data matrix, you may want to checkout [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635984/time-series-aggregation-efficiency). I'll give a shameless plug for my mex function over there :P  I didn't know about accumarray at the time, but I basically wrote accumarray for matrices.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Some more alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350735/is-there-an-accumarray-that-takes-matrix-as-val and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086874/matlab-find-and-apply-function-to-values-of-repeated-indices

Comment: @mikkola Thank you very much!!