# Keep terminal session between system() calls in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, shell

MATLAB opens a new session every time [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) is called.
I want to be able to keep the session open and perform several calls to it.

Ideally, this would work:

```
system('export DUMMY=2');
[~, out] = system('echo $DUMMY');
disp(out)
```

But it doesn't as each `system` call is separate. How can I get around this and keep one session running?

The code above can be fixed by using [`setenv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html), replacing the first line with `setenv('DUMMY', '2');`, but I am looking for a more general solution.

Comment: Don't know much about Matlab but this sounds like a classic use case for `popen()` where you would open a shell (e.g. `bash`) and write commands to it.... https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13851-popen-read-and-write?focused=5087638&tab=example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average of subgroup of 2nd column, grouped by 1st column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886945/average-of-subgroup-of-2nd-column-grouped-by-1st-column)

Answer (score 1):

Would something along these lines be suitable for you?

```
C:\Users\...>SET "foo=bar" & ECHO %foo%
bar
```

Windows batch files and command prompt allow to execute multiple commands on a single line concatenating them with `&`. Example with Matlab:

```
[~, out] = system('SET "foo=bar" & ECHO %foo%');
disp(out); % bar
```

Alternatively, you could create a `.bat` file to be called through the `system` function, whose behavior depends on the arguments you pass to it (read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-do-i-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file) for more information).

Comment: My solution is indeed running a bash script from a file (on Unix, not Windows), but this means code in the script must run more than once. For an `export` command this is not an issue. For more tasking commands it can be.